# como separar numero en C

Tags: c

queria preguntar si a alguien se le ocurre como puedo mostrar un numero que recibo por entrada, por ejemplo si recibo el 2354, como puedo mostrarlo asi :
2  3  5  4  . Separado por espacios

gracias de antemano

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Este código es para voltear un número dígito por dígito:

```
int x=2345,y=0,d=0;
while(x>0)
{
    d=x%10;
    y=y*10+d;
    x=(x-d)/10;
    printf("%d ",d);
}
```

'd' es el dígito y en cada vuelta va cambiando

Comment: lo malo es que si pones que muestre 'd' en cada vuelta, en lugar de mostrar   2 3 4 5, mostrará 5 4 3 2.

Comment: -1. Esto no responde la pregunta formulada por el OP.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro tu edición debería haber sido una publicación por separado porque realmente es un intento de respuesta y no una edición a lo escrito. Comprendo que no podías porque la pregunta estaba cerrada y no se admitían más respuesta, pero por algo la pregunta está cerrada. No es bueno "saltarse" el funcionamiento normal del sitio. Lee [answer] y [Editar Preguntas Y Respuestas](/help/privileges/edit) para más información.